# How to detect if browser supports "Add to Homescreen" on iOS

Tags: ios, browser, safari, progressive-web-apps, feature-detection

In iOS, Safari is the only browser with the "Add to Homescreen" feature.  I want to show instructions to the user how to use this feature, but only if this feature exists.  Is there a way to detect this feature?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ClientJS](https://github.com/jackspirou/clientjs) to detect what browser and operating system the website is run on, and from there show instructions to install the PWA.

If you try it, you can also detect if the website is already running as a PWA or in the browser using the following code :

```
function isPWA() {
    if (
      this.client.isMobileIOS() &&
      'standalone' in window.navigator &&
      // @ts-ignore
      window.navigator.standalone
    )
      return true;

    if (
      this.client.isMobileAndroid() &&
      window.matchMedia('(display-mode: standalone)').matches
    )
      return true;

return false;
}
```

Comment: I'm just wondering, since in iOS all non-Safari browsers are just wrappers for the Safari browser, can this tool you recommend differentiate between Safari and non-Safari browsers?  Cause that's really what it comes down to as Safari on iOS is the only browser with the ability to install a PWA, and as far as I know, even Chrome on iOS will identify itself as Safari, even though it can not install an app, so that's the problem I'm trying to solve.

Comment: Safari is no longer the only browser since 16.4, we are just waiting for the new version of chrome on iOS that will be able to install PWA at that point, probably a matter of weeks now. Otherwise yes, the tool can identify the various browsers so that before the user install the app, you can know if it's in safari or not (even after, but as you said right now on iOS it is only safari for PWA). As of today, we detect the browser on iOS and if it's not safari, then we ask the user to open the website in safari to install the PWA, all of that using clientjs.